# How to place a new element exactly where a user clicks?

Tags: javascript, css

I my project below, set up so when you click on the ball(pin), it follows and when you click a second time, the ball returns to its original parent, and a newly created ball is appended to a newly created div, which is appended to the parent of the element in which was clicked.

My Goal: to have the click be the exact point of where the newly created ball is positioned.

Issue: I have an alert that shows the coordinates of the click, and when I inspect element after clicking, it shows the newly created ball has acquired those properties. Problem is, not every time does it seem to line up exactly where I clicked.

I'm just getting into DOM manipulation, so please explain in detail, how you went about solving this problem.

Here is the code to be reviewed:

http://codepen.io/jobenscott/pen/EPZxzQ

```
if (elementMouseIsOver != theFrigginPin) {

     console.log("the one we want, but doesn't look like its working further");
     alert("x: " + relativeX + " y:" + relativeY);
     elementMouseParent.append($newHiddenElement);
     pinnedPinPositioned.appendTo($newHiddenElement);
     pinnedPinPositioned = brandNewPin.css({
       left: relativeX,
       // left: e.clientX,
       //top: e.clientY
       top: relativeY
     });

   } else if (elementMouseIsOver == theFrigginPin) {
     console.log("hitthepin");

   } else {
     conosle.log("notquitesure");
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this small example I made with jQuery and your CSS+HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/hzqhv8cw/1/

Comment: I have an updated example with the ability to place elements. https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/hzqhv8cw/2/

Comment: Wow, first question I've posted here, this really helps. Thanks for making this experience enjoyable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is about relativity. Your pin is positioned absolutely to your text container. This means that the values of `left` and `top` specify distances from the edge of this container, where as you are setting these values based on the full browser window in your code.

To demonstrate: scroll down, in your example, and then try to place the pin. Notice what happens.

You will either need to remove all margins/padding etc around your container elements so they align with the window exactly, or compensate for these in your code. Code would be better.

**A suggestion:**

- Record the mouse position when you click the pin.
- Move the pin around relative to the mouse using the `top` and `left` parameters instead.
- When you click, apply the last values for `top` and `left`.

This way, you are moving them around by the same means they will be positioned and therefore are guaranteed to be placed exactly.

Comment: You made a good explanation, though update someones code a little to make it work is not considered _code writing service_ so I suggest you take that part out of your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detailed response. I'll be sure to do a bit more digging next time.

Comment: @LGSon your right, it was a bit harsh. Sorry jobenscott, that part has been removed. In future, please try to include a specific question, other than just: _here is my code, it should do this but it doesn't..._ You'll get the hang of it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your pinholder, which cause your pin x/y values to depend on the pinholders x/y.

Here is an updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQeeOK?editors=001) (took out some markup/js) which works.

And here is its script, which is somewhat also cleaned up a little.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var click = false,
     top = 0,
     left = 0;

   $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {    
     if (click == true) {    
       $('#thePin').css({
         left: e.pageX - left,
         top: e.pageY - top
       });
     }    
   });

   $('#thePin').draggable().click(function(e) {
     top = e.pageY - top;
     left = e.pageX - left;
     click = !click;    
     if (click == false) {
       var noPoint = document.getElementById("thePin").style.pointerEvents = "none";    
       var x = e.pageX,
         y = e.pageY,
         theFrigginPin = document.getElementById('thePin'),
         elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
       var brandNewPin = $('<div class="newPinnedPin" id="newPinnedPin"></div>');
       var eventTarget = e.target,
         pinnedPinPositioned = brandNewPin.css({
           left: left,
           top: top
         });

       if (elementMouseIsOver != theFrigginPin) {    
         elementMouseParent.append($newHiddenElement);
         pinnedPinPositioned.appendTo($newHiddenElement);
         pinnedPinPositioned = brandNewPin.css({
           left: left,
           top: top
         });

       } else if (elementMouseIsOver == theFrigginPin) {
         console.log("hitthepin");

       } else {
         conosle.log("notquitesure");
       }

     }
     return false;
   });

   $('html').click(function(e) {    
     click = false;    
   });    
 });
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I do need the pinholder(scroller), so I will use your method and see how that works! Thanks.